# Multiple NuxtJS og:image Meta Tags

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, meta-tags, vue-meta

In the specification of [Open Graph protocol - Arrays](https://ogp.me/#array) it is documented that multiple versions of the type `og:image` may be arranged.

We use on components basis this structure in NuxtJS `ssr`:

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Home page'
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: 'Home page description'
        }
        // And others...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The goal is to have multiple nodes of the tag `<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/rock.jpg" />` generated by [NuxtJS Meta](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/meta-tags-seo/). The thinking is, since these are dynamic pages, to build an array and merge them into the `meta` array.

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: 'Home page'
    }
  },
  head() {
    return {
      title: this.title,
      meta: [
        {
          hid: 'description',
          name: 'description',
          content: 'Home page description'
        }
        // And others...
        ...this.getMetaOgImages
      ]
    }
  },
  computed: {
    getMetaOgImages() {

      const tempArr = []

      // this.images comes from map state vuex-store
      this.images.forEach(image => {

        tempArr.push(
          {
            hid: 'og:image',
            property: 'og:image',
            content: image.url
          },
          {
            hid: 'og:image:secure_url',
            property: 'og:image:secure_url',
            content: image.url
          }
        )
      })

      return tempArr
    }
  }
}
```

The computed property contains all urls, but in the browser (in the generated `<meta>` tags) only the first element is present.

It seems to me that `vue-meta` filters out the other elements because they are considered duplicates.

Can anyone confirm this or does anyone have experience with outputting multiple elements?
According to the specification this is valid and should not be a problem.

Comment: The properties `hid` ([more about this here](https://midstride.com/seo-for-nuxt-meta-tags/)) are properties that ensure that metafields are overwritten. The reason for this is that if you have nested components, and you have already defined a meta tag in a parent component and in a child component, it will be overwritten with the one from the child component (the one rendered later). More about this can be found in the [Unique metadata](https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/faq/#unique-metadata) section in the [vue-meta.nuxt.org](http://vue-meta.nuxt.org) specs.

Comment: But now we have `vmid` properties in our meta element. Since our application is an `SSR` (server side rendering) application, the `vmid` is required and cannot be omitted.
The `vmid` is needed to resolve the appropriate callback for this element during hydration.
One approach now would be that we use in the `vmid` not only the property `og:image` but `og:image:1`, `og:image:2`, `og:image:3` and so on.
Attention: only the `vmid` may be extended with the index + 1, but not the property `property: 'og:image'`! This must always be [according to the standard](https://ogp.me/#array).